# Change VS2013 WorkFlow Background

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis

I'm using the dark theme for VS2013.  The workflow designer background for a SSIS package is quite the eyesore.  It's a black background, which is fine, and has a white/creme colored lines.  I'm assuming that the lines are meant to be there to distinguish that it is the background and not an element, but it makes horizontal lines a pain to look at.  Also, the blue completion lines are barely visible.  So is there a way to change the color and get rid of the lines?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ30X.png)

NOTE:

The lines seem to only be there during debug, just noticed.  So if there is no way of removing them, it's not that big of a deal.